# Existence of finite dimensional representation of an algebra

Tags: rt.representation-theory, matrices, noncommutative-algebra

Let $m>1$ be an integer and let $A$ be the algebra generated by the elements
$\{u^i_j,v^i_j,\bar{u}^i_j, \bar{v}^i_j| 1\leq i,j\leq m\}$ quotient over the relations
\begin{eqnarray}
u^i_j v^k_l&=&v^k_j u^i_l,~~\forall i,j,k,l,\\
\sum_j u^i_j \bar{u}^j_k&=&\delta^i_k,~~~\forall i,k,\\
\sum_j v^i_j \bar{v}^j_k&=&\delta^i_k,~~~\forall i,k.
\end{eqnarray}
[the last two equations mean that $\bar{u},\bar{v}$ are the "matrix inverses" of $u,v$.]

Does $A$ have a finite dimensional representation?

Comment: So your algebra is the tensor square of the algebra generated by the $u_jî$ and the $\bar u_jî$ only?

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov There must be more relations, e. g. $u_1^1v^1_2=v^1_1u^1_2$

Comment: Why so? I am speaking just about the tensor product of the algebra by itself, not a symmetric one...

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov Sorry, I don't understand your notation $u_{j\hat{1}}$, what does $\hat{1}$ mean? Also, notice that the relation is $u^i_j v^k_l=v^k_j u^i_l$, not $u^i_j v^k_l=v^k_l u^i_j$, i.e. they don't commute.

Comment: This seems to be some MathJax artifact, $u^i_j$ and $\bar u^i_j$ were meant I think.

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov In the tensor product, every $u^i_j$ and every $\bar u^i_j$ commutes with every $v^k_l$ and every $\bar v^k_l$. Here I only see that $u^i_j$ commutes with $v^k_j$. Moreover I do not see at all whether any $\bar u^i_j$ or any $\bar v^k_l$ commutes with anything else. Moreover the first set of relations includes some which do not hold in the tensor product, e. g. the one in my previous comment.

Comment: Blind me… I did not see that the first condition was not about commuting, sorry —- $j$ and &l$ look so close…

Answer (score 1):

No, finite dimensional representations do not exist. This question is essentially asking if there exists invertible matrices $U_{13}\in \mathcal{X}\otimes I\otimes \mathcal{Y}$ and $V_{23}\in I\otimes \mathcal{X}\otimes  \mathcal{Y}$ such that $U_{1a}V_{2a}=V_{2a}U_{1a}\Pi_{12}$, where both sides belong to the algebra $\mathcal{X}\otimes\mathcal{X}\otimes\mathcal{Y}$ with $\mathcal{X}=M_m(\mathbb{C})$,  $\mathcal{Y}=M_{d}(\mathbb{C})$ ($d$ is the dimension of the representation), $I$ is the identity matrix, and $\Pi_{12}$ is the linear operator that swaps the first two tensor factor spaces.  My own answer to [this question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/29136/realizing-a-swap-gate-using-a-commutator-sequence-and-an-auxiliary-qudit) shows that finite dimensional invertible solutions to this equation do not exist, and gives a construction for an infinitie dimensional solution.

Comment: [Your answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/29351).